# Comparing and printing values in EMU8086

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I just started to learn `assembly` and I wrote some lines to practice, but I am stuck at the part where I need to display results.

**Description:** I have a `min` value and a `max` value. I am comparing those values with an `array`, trying to display only values that are not in the inteval ( `[min,max]` )

Here is what I have tried ( I know I am very bad at this, sorry !):

```
include emu8086.inc

ORG 100h   

mov cx, 5    

verificareMinim:   
           MOV AX,date                                                                                  
           MOV BX,minInterval                                                                                 
           CMP AX,BX 
           JB belowMinResults   

 loop verificareMinim      ; sfarsit pasul 1 



 verificareMaxim:  
            MOV AX,date 
            MOV BX,maxInterval
            CMP AX,BX
            JA  overMaxResults

  loop verificareMaxim  ; sfarsit pasul 2


 belowMinResults:
            int 21h
            JMP verificareMinim

 overMaxResults:  
            int 21h
            JMP verificareMaxim



maxInterval DW 10
minInterval DW 1
date DW -1,-4,11,3,7

RET ; return to operating system.
END ; directive to stop the compiler.
```

So, my questions are :

1) What is wrong in my code ?  (problem is described above, at `Description` )

2) How can I display results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print only numbers of an array that fit in range, you don't need to make it too complicated by using 2 loops. One loop is enough.

Another issue is that you don't set any meaningful parameters for the `int 21h` DOS call.

Third issue is that you don't update your pointers.

Fourth issue is that you don't set `cx` again after the first (`verificareMinim`) loop.

Fifth issue is that you use unsigned conditional jumps `jb` and `ja` for signed numbers.

Sixth issue is that your code gets in an infinite loop, because when `loop verificareMaxim` does not branch anymore to `verificareMaxim`, the execution continues to `belowMinResults` and then (if `int 21h` doesn't crash, that is), there `JMP verificareMinim` makes it an infinite loop.

Seventh issue is that `ret` instruction is after your data, and is never reached.

You could do something like this:

```
    mov si,date ; si points to the array.
                ; some assemblers want mov si,offset array.
                ; lea si,date may also be used.

    mov cx,5    ; length of array date
```

**Edit:** print numbers that are **not** in the interval. Fixed.

**Edit:** Fixed bug in hexadecimal printing.

```
@verify_loop:
    mov ax,[si]           ; read value from array into ax
    cmp ax,[minInterval]  ; compare value of ax with the value of min_Interval
                          ; some assemblers want cmp ax,min_Interval
    jl  @number_is_ok     ; jump if less, signed conditional jump.

    cmp ax,[maxInterval]  ; compare value of ax with the value of max_Interval
                          ; some assemblers want cmp ax,max_Interval
    jle @number_not_valid ; jump if less or equal, signed conditional jump.

@number_is_ok:

    ; the number in ax is valid, print it here.

    ; I'll do the printing here the easy way: printing in
    ; hexadecimal, printing in other formats (say, decimal) left as an exercise.
    ; hint: use div and print always the remainder after converting it to ASCII
    ; 0...9.
    ;
    ; I'll just use int 21h/ah=02h here, dl contains the character to write.

    push cx

    mov cl,12d ; number of bits to shift.
               ; start with 12 (it's 16 minus 4).

    @print_loop:
        mov dx,ax

        shr dx,cl   ; shift dx cl bits to the right
        and dl,0x0F ; leave only the lower nibble (4 bits)
        cmp dl,9
        jbe @between_0_and_9 ; jump if between or equal to 9
                             ; (unsigned conditional jump)

            add dl,('a'-'9'-1) ; Edit: fixed bug here.
                               ; Lowercase hexadecimal letters a-f
                               ; (change to 'A' for uppercase)
    @between_0_and_9:
        add dl,'0'           ; convert to printable ASCII '0'...'9', 'a' ... 'f'

        push ax    ; according to Ralph Brown's interrupt list,
                   ; int 21h/ah=02 modifies al.
        mov ah,2   ; print character to screen
        int 21h    ; character in dl
        pop ax

        sub cl,4        ; next time shift 4 bits less
        jnc @print_loop ; continue if there's still bits left

    pop cx

@number_not_valid:
    add si,2            ; next word in array date.
    dec cx              ; decrement counter.
    jnz @verify_loop    ; continue if there's still words in array date.

; now everything is done.

    mov ax,4C00h
    int 21h      ; int 21h/ah=4Ch, return to DOS, return code in al.
                 ; int 20h works too, no return code.
                 ; ret works too, but only in .COM files.

maxInterval DW 10
minInterval DW 1
date        DW -1, -4, 11, 3, 7
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to update the question, but I managed to do it by myself yestarday :D